# javascript url.indexOf equal to not contains

Tags: javascript, url, equals

i have this problem:
i use this:

```
url.indexOf('RpId=2') > -1
```

but what i am making the page do also happens when RpId=27 or 28.  i need it to be specifically 2, not "containing 2".

the total script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var url = document.location.href;
if( !(url.indexOf('RHViewStoryBoard.aspx') > -1 && ( 

url.indexOf('RpId=31') > -1 ||  url.indexOf('RpId=35') > -1 ||  url.indexOf('RpId=6') > -1  ||  url.indexOf('RpId=34') > -1 ||  url.indexOf('RpId=30') > -1 ||  url.indexOf('RpId=11') > -1|| url.indexOf('RpId=2') > -1     ) ) ){
      $('body').append('<style type="text/css">html body .customSlidesNav.customSlidesNavNext {display:block !important}html body .customSlidesNav.customSlidesNavNext {display:block !important}</style>')
}
});
</script>
```

and i have some css to go with it:

```
html .customSlidesNav.customSlidesNavNext {display: none !important;}
html .customSlidesNav.customSlidesNavPrev {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: Just [edit] your question.

Comment: Will the "RpId=2" be at the end (or all of) the string? i.e. it won't have stuff after it like "RpId=2&x=y" etc?

Comment: `indexOf` is not a good tool for this. You should parse the search string into key/value pairs. Then you can simply look for a match.

Comment: `"some string".search(/RpId=2\d/i)`

Comment: i am not 100% sure there will never be anything behind it. it appears now that i don't have anything else behind it. would there be an option for something if there isn't ?  i don't know much java i got this script and normally just adjust the rpid codes. but now that is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments looking for an exact match is probably the safest. You can use [urlSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to parse the query string. Also instead of a long if statement you can shorten it by using an array of valid rpids. Here is an example:

```js
let url = new URL('https://www.example.com/apath?query1=test&RpId=2&test2=test');
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
let rpid = searchParams.get("RpId");

const validRpids = ["31", "35", "6", "34", "30", "11", "2"];


// do any condition you want with RpId
// don't forget to parse RpId if you want to do something with the number and not a string
if(validRpids.includes(rpid)){
  console.log("rpid is valid: " + rpid);
}
else{
  console.log("rpid is NOT valid: " + rpid);
}
```

Comment: i have to get the url in the let url sentence right? should i have this: 
let url = window.location.href;       ?

Comment: @user2110914 glad to hear, feel free to also post your answer for future readers to learn from.